# Why is the output of my subprocess not being printed?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Here is my best attempt at asynchronously reading stdin/stdout from a subprocess and printing it from Python:

```
import asyncio
import subprocess

from asyncio.subprocess import STDOUT, PIPE, DEVNULL


async def start_stream():
    return await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        'watch ls /proc',
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=PIPE,
        limit=1024
    )


async def spawn():
    ev_proc = await start_stream()
    while True:
        stdout, stderr = await ev_proc.communicate()
        print(stdout, stderr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(spawn())
```

Why is the print function not outputting anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `watch` process never terminates and `communicate()` waits for the process to terminate, therefore `stdout` never arrives in your script.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html

> coroutine communicate(input=None)
>
> Interact with process: Send data to
>   stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.
>   **Wait for process to terminate.**

Try the following code which was inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/24435988/2776376.
It uses `pipe_data_received` and then `len > 16` is simply to prevent printing empty lines.

> SubprocessProtocol.pipe_data_received(fd, data)
>
> Called when the child process writes data into its stdout or stderr pipe. fd is the integer file descriptor of the pipe. data is a non-empty bytes object containing the data.

```
import asyncio

class SubprocessProtocol(asyncio.SubprocessProtocol):
    def pipe_data_received(self, fd, data):
        if fd == 1:
            text = data.decode()
            if len(text.strip()) > 16:
                print(text.strip())

    def process_exited(self):
        loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


ls = loop.run_until_complete(loop.subprocess_exec(
    SubprocessProtocol, 'watch', 'ls', '/proc'))
loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct way to do it

```
import asyncio

async def _read_stream(stream, cb):  
    while True:
        line = await stream.readline()
        if line:
            cb(line.decode().rstrip())
        else:
            break

async def _stream_subprocess(cmd, stdout_cb = lambda x: x, stderr_cb = lambda x: x):  
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*cmd,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)


    await asyncio.gather(
        _read_stream(process.stdout, stdout_cb),
        _read_stream(process.stderr, stderr_cb)
    )
    return await process.wait()


async def main():
    rc = await _stream_subprocess(["bash", "-c", "echo stdout && sleep 1 && echo stderr 1>&2 && sleep 2 && echo done"],
         lambda x: print("STDOUT: %s" % x),
         lambda x: print("STDERR: %s" % x),
     )
    print(rc)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

you can read more here, another implementation, using protocols
https://blog.dalibo.com/2022/09/12/monitoring-python-subprocesses.html